# What's difference between escape_string and real_escape_string?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on dreamviewer. When i'm trying to write basic syntax it usually autocompletes. [image]

As you see it offers 2 variants for "escape": real_escape_string and escape_string. I wonder, Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php) is an alias to [`real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), so they're identical.

Comment: Edit: for mysqli you're absolutely right. For regular mysql it's a different function, and even deprecated. :)

Comment: In many cases escape_string and real_escape_string are not identical. escape_string is vulnerable and so real_escape_string should be used instead (don't ask me why they didnt just change escape_string so it worked, backwards compatibility issues).